# ArcGIS classification and accuracy assessment NoData class and error generating accuracy points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, nodata, image-classification

I'm trying to classify a clipped Landsat raster and then do an accuracy check for a watershed. When I do classify my clipped watershed, the region outside the ROI also gets classified i.e. the NoData values beyond the watershed boundaries as UNIQUE.PIXEL.VALUES 255. This separate class is then becoming a problem when generating accuracy points using Create Accuracy Assessment Points as the generated points are being distributed throughout the rectangular extent beyond my study area.

Is this an issue with how I classified my clipped raster or something to do with the point generation tool?

[image]

Comment: It appears from the screen grab you're using ArcGIS Desktop but you have a tag for ArcGIS Pro, which software are you using? This result is odd but you can define the NoData on the classifed raster to 255 before running your next step. If it's part of a process you can use Set Raster Properties https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015z000000 to define the NoData.

Comment: I have access to both Pro and 10.8 (apologies, the grab here is from 10.8). I've tried workarounds using IsNull and Reclass to recode the NoData to a defined value (255/0), While that works visually, the classifier still considers that as a valid pixel value and creates a separate thematic class which is why the points are distributed across. A crude workaround i followed was to reclip the classified image to get back the NoData extent and then generate the points. It worked but I would like to find a better solution as this may cause problems when I plan to use my classified image further.